# Add .winmd lib to Win32/C++ project - is it possible?

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, winmd

We have Win32/C++ project with Desktop Bridge and usual method adding .winmd (by add reference) library didn't works, so is there another path to do it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/winrt-cref/winmd-files

Comment: What should the outcome of *"adding [a] .winmd"* be? It's not a library, and neither contains code nor anything a linker would care about.

Comment: @IInspectable .winmd can be a complete library too.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476957/WINMDplusFilesplusUnderplustheplusHood

Comment: A .winmd file repurposes the PE image file format, and thus could hold everything a "regular" executable contains. Though standard tooling will ignore everything but the CLR section. Which comes back to the initial question: What should the result of adding (a reference to) a .winmd file be?

Comment: We have library https://publisher.vungle.com/sdk/sdks/windows and we need link it to the win32 project -- it's all I know @IInspectable